# burn the midnight oil [doing something entertaining]

Tags: idioms

Can we burn the midnight oil doing something entertaining?
Is the following natural?

> John is burning the midnight oil playing video games.

Comment: Every definition of “burning the midnight oil” I’ve seen says “working or studying”. Why do you think think it’s defined as something other than that?

Comment: An American said it could be used for activities other than working and studying.

Comment: And why did you not include that in your question?

Comment: To be fair, I have occasionally heard this used for other activities than studying or working (AmE), though this is uncommon and it looks to be incorrect. In short, as an AmE speaker, I'd say don't use it the way you're considering.